# Given the determinant determine the value of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

You are given that the determinant of the matrix A =
 \begin{matrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{matrix} is equal to 5.  Using this information and the property of determinants determine the value of \begin{matrix}
        2a+3c & 2b+3d \\
        a & b  \\
        \end{matrix}

Comment: Do you know what happens when you switch rows/columns in a determinant? What happens if you add one row to the other?

Comment: I know adding one multiple of one row to another preserves the determinant, multiplying an entire row by a constant multiplies the determinant by that constant and interchanging two rows multiplies the determinant by -1

Answer (score 1):

Using the linearity of the determinant function

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
        2a+3c & 2b+3d \\
        a & b  \\
        \end{vmatrix} & = \begin{vmatrix}
        2a & 2b \\
        a & b  \\
        \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
        3c & 3d \\
        a & b  \\
        \end{vmatrix}\\
&=0 + \begin{vmatrix}
        3c & 3d \\
        a & b  \\
        \end{vmatrix}\\
&=3\begin{vmatrix}
        c & d \\
        a & b  \\
        \end{vmatrix}\\
&=-15.
\end{align*}
You should try to see which properties have been used for each step.

Comment: A few questions..so I understand how you broke the matrix up but how come the plus signs disappeared? Why isn't it 2a+b and 3c+3d?

Comment: Also,when you divide 2a and 2b by 2 and you are left with a b over a b why is that 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @Lil I would recommend you to look up some notes on determinants and their properties. That will help you understand things better. Specially your second question suggests that you need to revise the definitions before attempting this question.

Comment: @Lil here is a place to start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant